# Two instances of django admin site - templates

Tags: python, django

for some reason I need to have two different instances of Django Admin Site in my project - default admin site and an instance of class inheriting from AdminSite.

So I created a class `MyAdminSite(AdminSite)`

Then I wrote something like:

```
my_admin_site = MyAdminSIte(name='myadmin')
```

Then I added proper entry in urls.py.

Everything works fine.

But now i want to customize some templates.
In settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),)
```

Then I created directories:
    `/PROJECTDIR/templates/admin` 
and `/PROJECTDIR/templates/myadmin`

The thing is, I simply cannot extend/override templates in 'myadmin' django admin site.
For example, if I add, let's say an empty 'base_site.html' into /templates/admin/, then both admin sites becomes blank.

But when I add same file into /templates/myadmin/, nothing happenes.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override class variables of `AdminSite` to  specify different templates:

```
app_index_template = None
login_template = None
logout_template = None
password_change_template = None
password_change_done_template = None
```

You can also override class variables of `ModelAdmin` to specify different templates:

```
add_form_template = None
change_form_template = None
change_list_template = None
delete_confirmation_template = None
delete_selected_confirmation_template = None
object_history_template = None
```

For example:

```
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    app_index_template = "my/new/admin/app_index.html"
```

Comment: Yes, I actually know that. But is there any option to do this in the same way as with default django admin site?

Comment: Yes, you can subclass AdminSite and use that object instead. For example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf

Comment: But I'm actually subclassing AdminSite and it works pretty fine, except templates. Did we just misunderstand each other?

Comment: If you want the templates of the default admin to change as well then you'll need to use a subclass of AdminSite there as well. So for each admin interface that you wish to have with different templates, you'll need to create a subclass of AdminSite with the template variables above. Or, you can replace the default templates as normal and specify new templates for your second admin by using the variables in the above answer.

Comment: Ok, so this is the only way to do that? The only way to customize templates of a subclass of AdminSite is to modify this variables you mentioned? Even if, let's say, I'm not gonna modifying default admin?

Comment: Yes, looking at the source that's the provided method for modifying templates.